# Obfuscate URL path to Moodle subsite

Tags: url, drupal, obfuscation, moodle

I have a Drupal site and a Moodle subsite within Drupal.

At the moment, the URL structure to access Moodle is as follows: `www.mydrupal.com/moodle`

I don't want users going directly to Moodle when they return, i.e. they always have to access Moodle via a link in Drupal. This helps to set some essential session variables.

**So, is there a way to obfuscate the Moodle part of the URL - like a sequence of characters which is altered at regular intervals?**
i.e., `www.mydrupal.com/owhefihewhf`

I want to use such a measure to discourage bookmarking the Moodle part of the site. Can anyone recommend such a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the URL of your moodle regularly would involve updating the moodle database each time you change the URL.

The easiest workaround which prevents the mentioned case above (bookmarking) would be an page, which includes moodle using an Iframe, like (www.mydrupal.com/learning). So the actual moodle URL would not be visible to the common visitor. The mentioned page can check if session varaibles exist, if so, show iframe, otherwise redirect to Drupal/Loginpage.

Another option would be having an own authentification plugin in Moodle, which will either user Drupal authentification for a SSO, or at least check if your session variables are set.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had not thought of using an iFrame but is an iFrame based solution in anything pertaining to web development not a potential security loop hole?

Comment: It depends on your goals you want to reach. If its just to prevent bookmarking the actual Moodle URL, i see no issue here. If you want to achieve that your session variables are set in 100%, before users login to moodle, you will have definitely to change login behavior of moodle, like auth plugin. Even if you go your suggested way (changing url of moodle regularly), there would be the potential risk that users bookmark the temporary URL in the meantime and might hit your moodle without the session variables, until you change the url again.

Comment: Another option would be (maybe) doing the stuff via apache htaccess. You might check for existing cookie/headers, until they are not set, users cannot access your moodle dir

Comment: You are correct  about the temporary URL not being a foolproof solution but it's more to do with discourage users bookmarking and sharing the Moodle URL. Users could simply decided to login directly to Moodle instead of going through Drupal. Login directly to Moodle would be possible but the App experience would be diminished. As you can imagine and appreciate, Drupal and Moodle have very different strenghts. So, your initial suggestion of using an iFrame is very interesting and invites further research.